# delete list using JPA

Tags: jpa

I have list to be deleted. 
My code to delete my list is:

```
for (MyDataModel dataMo: listData) {
    testEJB.delete(dataMo.getPkId(), MyDataModel.class);
    }

public void delete(Object id, Class<T> classe) {
    T entityToBeRemoved = em.getReference(classe, id);

    em.remove(entityToBeRemoved);
}
```

Since my list size may be more than 500, data deletion by this method is much time consuming.I want alternative so that deletion is quicker.I need help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have got solution on my own for this i used native query.Here i do not have to generate the list too.My code is:

```
public int deleteUsingNativeQuery(String query){
    Query qry = em.createNativeQuery(query );
    return qry.executeUpdate();
}
```

Here i pass the native query "delete from 'table name' where 'condition'" in function deleteUsingNativeQuery and deletion was also quick.

Comment: which you could also do using JPQL BULK DELETE by query